# XSL Transform nested elements into attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a object that is using xml for it's menu.  I want to generate the xml from my database, however the object wants its information as attributes rather than elements.

The problem isn't so much as converting elements into attributes, that I can do.  The problem is that the submenus are of unspecified depths and each menu item  can be either an actual menu item, or parent to a submenu, or both.

Is it possible to do this in Xslt?

Starting XML

```
<MenuDataSet>
  <Menu>
    <ChildID>0</ChildID>
    <ParentID></ParentID>
    <Title>Main Menu</Title>
   <PageURL></PageURL>
   <Menu>
      <ChildID>2</ChildID>
      <ParentID>0</ParentID>
      <Title>Title 2</Title>
      <PageURL>pageurl2.com</PageURL>
      <SortOrder>3</SortOrder>
      <Menu>
        <ChildID>3</ChildID>
        <ParentID>2</ParentID>
        <Title>Title 3</Title>
        <PageURL>Pageurl3.com</PageURL>
        <SortOrder>9</SortOrder>
        <Menu>
          <ChildID>4</ChildID>
          <ParentID>3</ParentID>
          <Title>Title 4</Title>
          <PageURL>Pageurl4.com</PageURL>
          <SortOrder>1</SortOrder>
        </Menu>
      </Menu>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
      <ChildID>1</ChildID>
      <ParentID>0</ParentID>
      <Title>Title 1</Title>
      <PageURL>Pageurl1.com</PageURL>
      <SortOrder>4</SortOrder>
      <BaseModel>AX25L</BaseModel>
    </Menu>
  </Menu>
</MenuDataSet>
```

Desired resulting XML (the extra elements such as ChildID, ParentID, SortOrder can be included, however I'd rather they not be)

```
<MenuDataSet>
   <Menu Title="Main Menu">
      <Menu Title="Title 2" PageURL="pageurl2.com">
         <Menu Title="Title 3" PageURL="pageurl3.com">
            <Menu Title="Title 4" PageURL="pageurl4.com"/>
         </Menu>
      </Menu>
  </Menu>
  <Menu Title="Title 1" PageURL="pagurl1.com"/>
</MenuDataSet>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or shortly:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Menu | (Title | PageURL) [string()]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Title | PageURL">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I used Michael's as it was the shortest.. but all of them are spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Just start with an [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and then override as necessary...

**XML**

```
<MenuDataSet>
    <Menu>
        <ChildID>0</ChildID>
        <ParentID></ParentID>
        <Title>Main Menu</Title>
        <PageURL></PageURL>
        <Menu>
            <ChildID>2</ChildID>
            <ParentID>0</ParentID>
            <Title>Title 2</Title>
            <Menu>
                <ChildID>3</ChildID>
                <ParentID>2</ParentID>
                <Title>Title 3</Title>
                <PageURL>Pageurl3.com</PageURL>
                <SortOrder>9</SortOrder>
                <Menu>
                    <ChildID>4</ChildID>
                    <ParentID>3</ParentID>
                    <Title>Title 4</Title>
                    <PageURL>Pageurl4.com</PageURL>
                    <SortOrder>1</SortOrder>
                </Menu>
            </Menu>

            <PageURL>pageurl2.com</PageURL>
            <SortOrder>3</SortOrder>
        </Menu>
        <Menu>
            <ChildID>1</ChildID>
            <ParentID>0</ParentID>
            <Title>Title 1</Title>
            <PageURL>Pageurl1.com</PageURL>
            <SortOrder>4</SortOrder>
            <BaseModel>AX25L</BaseModel>
        </Menu>
    </Menu>
</MenuDataSet>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Menu">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|Title[string()]|PageURL[string()]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Menu"/>            
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Title|PageURL">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<MenuDataSet>
   <Menu Title="Main Menu">
      <Menu Title="Title 2" PageURL="pageurl2.com">
         <Menu Title="Title 3" PageURL="Pageurl3.com">
            <Menu Title="Title 4" PageURL="Pageurl4.com"/>
         </Menu>
      </Menu>
      <Menu Title="Title 1" PageURL="Pageurl1.com"/>
   </Menu>
</MenuDataSet>
```

If you're using XSLT 2.0, you could simplify the `Menu` template...

```
<xsl:template match="Menu">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="(@*,(Title|PageURL)[string()],Menu)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is actually pretty good at dealing with the often recursive nature of XML data structures.

This XSLT stylesheet for instance should produce your desired resulting XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="MenuDataSet">
    <MenuDataSet>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Menu" />
    </MenuDataSet>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="Menu">
    <Menu Title="{Title}">
      <xsl:if test="PageURL != ''">
        <xsl:attribute name="PageURL"><xsl:value-of select="PageURL"/></xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Menu" />
    </Menu>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The trick is using templates which apply themselves on any child nodes. The key in this template is the `<xsl:apply-templates select="Menu" />` element. It is responsible for calling the menu template (in our case) recursively.

Comment: This works excellent too... I especially appreciate you explaining about the select.  Some how I was over thinking things.